# exabgp heathcheck session bgp

Tags: bgp, bgp-ipv6

I've been trying to use [exabgp](https://github.com/Exa-Networks/exabgp). I know how to to issue command to the exabgp however i struggle to find whole list of commands the application accepts. With that I can't find a way to receive information about status of connection with bgp.

In logs I can see lots of communication between the two

```
14:55:45 | 1      | ka-outgoing-1   | send-timer 56 second(s) left
14:55:47 | 1      | ka-outgoing-1   | receive-timer 120 second(s) left
14:55:47 | 1      | ka-outgoing-1   | send-timer 55 second(s) left
14:55:47 | 1      | outgoing-1      | received TCP payload (  19) FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF 0013 04
14:55:47 | 1      | outgoing-1      | << message of type KEEPALIVE
```

however any of this it does not go on stdin of the application defined in config.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any more documentation other than what's in the repository.  You might try asking the developers.  They're available on Slack

Comment: You've rewritten the question, but my comment still stands/

Comment: @RonTrunk I did not re-write the question. I added some logs... Do not slender me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after investigation it's possible to use `exabgp.in`

```
echo "show neighbor summary" >> /run/exabgp/exabgp.in
```

and this will return on the `exabgp.out` the status

```
Peer            AS        up/down state       |     #sent     #recvd
1.1.1.1         100       5:19:36 established           3          2
done
```

you can fallow it with
`tail -f /run/exabgp/exabgp.out`